# autofill in chrome, textfield recognised as password textfield

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, textfield, autofill

```
<form id="formzap" name="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="textfield" class="ind" id="textzap" onkeypress="fadefx.init('noise', 1)" onblur="fadefx.init('noise', 0)" autofocus autocomplete="off"/>
<button type="submit" name="button" class="ind" id="buttonzap" value=""></button>
</form>
```

Hi!! Here's the html i used for a part of the homepage of my website...
There's a problem thought... I don't know why this textfield is recognised by Chrome as a password textfield and it automatically fill it with a password (showed)
For now i disabled the autocomplete, i don't know how to disable the autofill and i don't think this might be the answer i'm looking for...
I would like to know why this textfield is recognised as a password textfield by google chrome...
Did someone has a clue on this?
I really hope so!! Thanks :)

Comment: set autocomplete attribute as off like this <form id="formzap" name="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 0):

Set autocomplete attribute as off to form

eg

```
<form id="formzap" name="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: emmm... i already do that. it doesn't work.
it prevent the browser to autocomplete the word if i press the first key, but when i first load the page the browser automatically fill the textfield with a string (which is a password of mine)
plus, the main problem for me is not to disable the autofill, is to understand why the browser think that textfield is a password textfield!! O.ò